# Get Current item ViewPageAdapter Android

Tags: android

Im searching in all internet but I dont find any REAL solution about my problem.

I have a class with a Viewpager. (Class DescripcionRutinas)

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addNumDias(numDias);
    adapter.setDias(dias);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);

}
```

And I have a ViewPagerAdapter

```
 class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int numDias;
    private int count = 0;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }
    ArrayList<Dia> dias;

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        OneFragmentSeries fragmento = new OneFragmentSeries();

        Dia ex = dias.get(**I NEED CURRENT ITEM HERE**);
        nomDia = ex.getNombre();

        fragmento.setSeries((ArrayList<Serie>)((ArrayList<Dia>)WorkoutYourself.dameWorkoutYourself().dameRutina(nomRutina).getDias()).get(position).getSeries());
        return fragmento;
    }
```

I need the current item position here.

NOTE: ViewPagerAdapter is INSIDE DescripcionRutinas.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you mean current position of your visible viewPager ?

Comment: Yes, im using tabs, but "position" dont give me the current tab, gives me the next tab, And, when I arrives to final tab, the var "position" only gives me the last tab all time.

Comment: have you tried yourViewPager.get(position)?

Comment: Yes, see my comment. Position dont return the current real position

Comment: I don't know why do you need that but you can try passing the `ViewPager` instance in your Adapter's constructor and then you can access its any of the  public methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `yourViewPager.getCurrentItem()` it should work to get your visible pager position.

**Update**

`onPageSelected(int currentPage)` should do the stuff

```
dia.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int currentPage) {
        //here you get your current position
    }

});
```

Comment: The problem is, How can I use this command inside "getItem" method, if getItem is inside "yourViewPager"?

Comment: my pleasure... Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Read this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)

```
 viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int positionCurrentPage) {
           if(positionCurrentPage == 1){  // if you want the second page, for example
               //Your code here
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```